# html video tag (some mp4 videos work, some not)

Tags: html, spring-mvc, html5-video, video-embedding

I am using this:

```
<video class="video" controls="" width="100%" src="videopath/videoname.mp4"></video>
```

for some mp4 videos to work on my website. I used this for 3 videos, all of them being mp4, but only one of them is working, the others are not found, in Google Chrome I get a black player with no video, in Internet explorer I get something as "invalid path or file format". What can be the cause of this?

Comment: can you post the code and are you sure about the videos? I hope they are there in the videopath folder

Comment: I don't know what other code can be relevant, given the one that I shared (in which I generally replaced my path with videopath and my video name with videoname.mp4). The 3 videos are 100% in the same path, all of them are mp4, but only one of them is playing, with EXACTLY the same code used, minus the name of the video, of course.

Comment: paste here the code of all the 3 videos

Comment: are you sure the path is right to your video?

Comment: <video class="video" controls="" width="100%" src="video/cdr.mp4"></video> - this one is working.

<video class="video" controls="" width="100%" src="video/ld.mp4"></video>

<video class="video" controls="" width="100%" src="video/tsr.mp4"></video>

I don't know what other part of my code can be relevant. It's these video tags+ the fact that the videos are placed in the same folder, no?

Comment: Stefan , I am absolutely positive. Also, one more of them is working in Internet Explorer, so that's weird, having the same format and all.

Comment: can you check the chrome console? (f12) If there are any errors.

Comment: yes, I get this error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS. I think that I should have also mentioned that I use Spring and my project is ran as a Spring Boot App, maybe this is relevant also.

Comment: Then im not sure I never used Spring Boot App myself. Is it really not possible you can give some more code? If your video tag/path is right the problem should be somewhere else in the code.

Comment: it's so strange, when I click inspect element on the black screen videos, I see that the video it is seen, the video name appears, so the link is done, but it just won't play.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the resolution of the videos which are not being played and the one which is played. If the resolution is too high and the video box is small the videos are not played.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem as the videos resolution  is pretty small. But I will try to make a larger video box, thanks.